# No colours in gcovr 5.0 --html-details report

Tags: code-coverage, gcov, gcovr

I've been using the `gcovr` module for monthly report generation. I work on docker, so each time I used to download the `gcovr` module using `pip3` command on my Linux container.
Recently, after downloading the module, I realized that the version of the `gcovr` has been upgraded from `4.2` to `5.0` and the earlier commands were not working properly.

Earlier command used for report generation:

```
gcovr -g --keep --html-details --html-title "TITLE" --html-medium-threshold 60 --html-high-threshold 80 --gcov-ignore-parse-errors >> report.html
```

With `gcovr 5.0`, usage of the above command threw below error:

```
(ERROR) a named output must be given,if the option --html-details is used
```

Then, as per the suggestions from the above error, I used the command below:

```
gcovr -g --keep --html-details -o report.html --html-title "TITLE" --html-medium-threshold 60 --html-high-threshold 80 --gcov-ignore-parse-errors
```

But, I believe the above command is not fully correct and with the above command, the format of the report generated is not correct and also there are a lot of unwanted `*.css` files getting generated in the respective folders.

As you can see from the image below, the colour is not getting highlighted as per the percentage defined in "Legend":

[image: gcovr 5.0 report:]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `--html-details` report format generates one HTML file per source file, and an index file. Since gcovr 5.0, their shared CSS is stored as a separate file. This is important for the security configuration of some web servers.

- When you copy or move the html-details reports, you must copy all associated files: all the `.html` and `.css` files.
- You can force the CSS to be embedded into each HTML file using the `--html-self-contained` option. This e.g. makes it possible to send a single report file via email, but the links won't work. This option was announced as part of the [gcovr 5.0 changelog](https://gcovr.com/en/5.0/changelog.html#june-2021).
- It seems you are only interested in the index file, not in the source code-level details. If so, consider using the `--html` report format instead which generates a single file by default.

Additional remarks:

- If you want to force a specific gcovr version, you can tell pip to e.g. `pip install 'gcovr ~= 4.2'`. The [`~=` version specifier](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/#version-specifiers) selects the most recent *compatible* release, thus avoiding unexpected changes.
- All output formats can take the output name directly. Instead of `--html -o foo.html` you can write `--html foo.html`.
- The option `--gcov-ignore-parse-errors` is only intended as a temporary bandaid to keep you CI pipeline running in case you've updated to a GCC version that made incompatible changes to the .gcov report format. If there are errors without this option, that is a bug in gcovr and should be [reported](https://gcovr.com/en/stable/contributing.html#how-to-report-bugs). With this option you'll still get a report, but the report is likely to be incorrect.
- The gcovr option `-g`/`--use-gcov-files` is easy to use incorrectly. You almost certainly will get wrong results unless you use the gcov option `-l`/`--long-file-names`.